# Upload file by .NetCore and Angular On S3 - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-sdk

I want to upload an image on S3 by .NetCore and Angular, Actually I want to create a signed URL with the key and the secret key and ... in the backend, and then I want to upload the file in the angular by the generated URL in the backend

my backend code in .net :

```
 public  ServiceResponse GetPreSigned(FileCategory prepend, string append = null)
    {
        var mediaId = Guid.NewGuid();
        var config = new AmazonS3Config
        {
            SignatureVersion = "v4",
            RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1,
            ServiceURL = _config.LIARA_ENDPOINT
        };

        var amazonS3Client = new AmazonS3Client(_config.LIARA_ACCESS_KEY, _config.LIARA_SECRET_KEY, config);

        Amazon.S3.Model.GetPreSignedUrlRequest ccc = new Amazon.S3.Model.GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
        {
            BucketName = _config.LIARA_BUCKET_NAME,
            Key = GenerateResourceKey(mediaId, prepend.ToString(), append),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
            Verb = HttpVerb.PUT,
        };
        
        return new GetMediaPostRequestSuccess
        {
            MediaKey = GenerateResourceKey(mediaId, prepend.ToString(), append),
            BucketUri = amazonS3Client.GetPreSignedURL(ccc)
        };
    }
```

and the angular code is :

```
  uploadFile(file: any, preSignedUrl: GetMediaPostRequestSuccess): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
// Upload file by using the signed URL 
return this._http.put(preSignedUrl.bucketUri, formData, {
  headers: { 'dont-modify-this-one': ''}, // To Avoid Add Autorization Header by Intercepter
  observe: 'events'
})
```

and I got the below message as a response :
**The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.**

also this is my request params :
[image]

I think I missed something in the request header like Authorization.

**Can I use GetPreSignedURL to upload a file? is GetPreSignedURL responsible for signature and all security issues?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting ContentType in GetPreSignedUrlRequest, solved the problem

```
        Amazon.S3.Model.GetPreSignedUrlRequest config = new Amazon.S3.Model.GetPreSignedUrlRequest()
        {                
            BucketName = _config.LIARA_BUCKET_NAME,
            Key = GenerateResourceKey(mediaId, request.FileCategory.ToString(), request.Append ),
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
            Verb = HttpVerb.PUT,

            ContentType = string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.FileType) ? "application/octet-stream" : request.FileType
        };

        return amazonS3Client.GetPreSignedURL(config);
```

Also on the client side, we don't need to pass the formData, just pass the file as payload

```
uploadFile(file: any, preSignedUrl: GetMediaPostRequestSuccess): 
Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  return this._http.put(preSignedUrl.bucketUri, file, {
    headers: {
     'dont-modify-this-one': '',
     'Content-Type': file.type !== '' ? file.type : application/octet-stream'
  },
  reportProgress: true,
  observe: 'events'
})
```

}